# How to refresh APPLET without reloading the page in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, applet, refresh

i just want to refresh an applet without reloading the whole page in asp.net using javascript.
I tried `document.applets.view.refresh()` and kept this `<param name='cache_option' value='no'>`  line in applet code. In both the cases i'm failed.
can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It will fail unless you have a cross-domain.xml that allows it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```